# Code optimization : style display

Tags: javascript, optimization

I made this 2 functions based on different sessions, which displays/hides diffrent HTML code according to the session. Any idea on how this could could be simplified? If it possible at all to write it with less and better code?

```
// HTML / user interface for ADMIN view
function showAdminInterface() {       
      lblDropdown.style.display = "flex";
      lblDropdownforMobileOnly.style.display ="none";
      btnCreateProduct.style.display = "flex"; 
      btnCreateUser.style.display = "flex";
      pageViewProducts.style.display ="flex";
      btnSignupNav.style.display = "none";
      btnLoginNav.style.display = "none";
      btnSubscribeNav.style.display = "none";

}

  /************************************************************************/
  /************************************************************************/
  /************************************************************************/


  // HTML / user interface for USER view
  function showUserInterface() {

      lblDropdown.style.display = "flex";
      lblDropdownforMobileOnly.style.display ="none";
      pageViewProducts.style.display ="flex";
      btnEditUsersNav.style.display = "none";
      btnEditProductsNav.style.display = "none";
      btnViewSubscribersNav.style.display = "none";
      btnCreateProduct.style.display = "none";
      btnCreateUser.style.display = "none";
      btnSignupNav.style.display = "none";
      btnLoginNav.style.display = "none";

  }
```

Comment: Add a boolean flag `isAdmin` to one of your functions and a conditional `if/else`, or instead of conditional ternary conditions.

Comment: could you show me an example with code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the shared style changes like this:

```
function initInterface() {
    lblDropdown.style.display = "flex";
    lblDropdownforMobileOnly.style.display ="none";
    pageViewProducts.style.display ="flex";
    btnSignupNav.style.display = "none";
    btnLoginNav.style.display = "none";
}

function showAdminInterface() {  
    initInterface();
    btnCreateProduct.style.display = "flex"; 
    btnCreateUser.style.display = "flex";
    btnSubscribeNav.style.display = "none";
}


function showUserInterface() {
    initInterface();
    btnEditUsersNav.style.display = "none";
    btnEditProductsNav.style.display = "none";
    btnViewSubscribersNav.style.display = "none";
    btnCreateProduct.style.display = "none";
    btnCreateUser.style.display = "none";
}
```

and you can create helper function for show and hide:

```
function hide(el) {
    el.style.display = "none"; // you can do the same with show and flex
}

function showUserInterface() {
    initInterface();
    hide(btnEditUsersNav);
    hide(btnEditProductsNav);
    hide(btnViewSubscribersNav);
    hide(btnCreateProduct);
    hide(btnCreateUser);
}
```

or

```
function showUserInterface() {
    initInterface();

    [
        btnEditUsersNav,
        btnEditProductsNav,
        btnViewSubscribersNav,
        btnCreateProduct,
        btnCreateUser
    ].forEach(hide);
}
```

Comment: I like the last one, and you can couple it with my answer to make it in one function.

Comment: Yeah, the problem, is not all the elements are hided / shown in a both place in that case, it would be possible to write a really nice looking compact code :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the example, but you get the idea.

```
 function showInterface(isAdmin = false) {
     lblDropdown.style.display = isAdmin ? "flex" : "none";
     ... // the rest
 }
```